# How to set policy on GCP that time-limits validity of gcloud credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When one does "gcloud auth login", the credentials are stored on the local system.

Is there a way to set a policy on an organisation in GCP that will ensure all credentials will be time-limited, so that users need to reauthenticate regularly?

My main concern is that these credential files may fall into the wrong hands, i.e. if a developer's laptop is stolen, or a roommate may access a developer's laptop. Time limiting the validity of these tokens will limit the damage somewhat.

I know users can do "gcloud auth revoke", or go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions an revoke Google Cloud SDK permissions there, but both are manual processes.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible at the moment within Google Cloud Platform. I suggest submitting a feature request about it by following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). It could be possible through G suite and per this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/new-oauth-protections-to-reduce-risk).

However, one way to go around this, and while the user changes his Google account sign-in password in case if the laptop was stolen, is to revoke Google Cloud SDK’s access (to the account) as indicated in this [document](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en).

```
"sign-in & security" > "Manage Apps" > "Google Cloud SDK"
```

Thus, the tokens will not work anymore, and a token refresh will fail throwing an error similar to this:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login
```

This should remain the case (for the intruder) even after the (legitimate) user authenticates the SDK `gcloud auth login` on a different machine which should automatically re-add the Google Cloud SDK back to the account, but with different Oauth credentials .